# Overloading equivalence (==) operator for custom class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading, equivalence

Is it possible to overload equivalence (==) operator for a custom class inside that custom class. However I know that it is possible to have this operator overloaded outside class scope. Appreciate any sample code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial)

Comment: This might be interesting in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793218/swift-overriding-in-subclass-results-invocation-of-in-superclass-only.

Answer (score 36):

Add global functions. For example:

```
class CustomClass {
    var id = "my id"
}

func ==(lhs: CustomClass, rhs: CustomClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
func !=(lhs: CustomClass, rhs: CustomClass) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs == rhs)
}
```

#### To conform Equatable protocol in Swift 2

```
class CustomClass: Equatable {
    var id = "my id"
}

func ==(left: CustomClass, right: CustomClass) -> Bool {
    return left.id == right.id
}
```

#### To conform Equatable protocol in Swift 3

```
class CustomClass {
    var id = "my id"
}

extension CustomClass: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: CustomClass, rhs: CustomClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this WAY too fast (like I did), note that those func declarations are OUTSIDE of the class (hence, "global").

Comment: note that the above operators won't get fired if one of the operands is an optional. also, if both the operator's parameters are optionals, and both the operands are non-optionals, it won't get fired. make both the operator's parameters implicitly unwrapped optionals to ensure it will always be fired for your custom class; but ensure nil cases are handled, otherwise your program may crash

Answer (score 6):

No, operators are overloaded using global functions.