# Can (a == 1 && a == 2 && a ==3) equal true?

Tags: swift

I saw [this JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true), and I'm wondering if it is possible to do the same in Swift.

**Is this possible?**

```
if a==1 && a==2 && a==3 {
    print("amazing")
}
```

If so, then how?

Comment: Yes, using several of the same techniques.

Comment: nice , but why downvote?

Comment: Wasn't mine, but the question you linked to was at -7 before it received an answer.

Comment: `extension Int { static func == (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool { return true } }` ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848119/overloading-equivalence-operator-for-custom-class-in-swift looks like in swift you can use global functions to overload the `==` operator

Comment: yes it can be achievable by overloading `==` operator

Comment: @Hamish Or `return [1, 2, 3].contains(rhs)`  :)

Comment: Or even `func && (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool { return true }` :D

Comment: Or you could do https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/94652e3e8dfd9e92726810eb987892c2. Basically there are quite a few ways you could go about doing this; therefore IMO this question is too broad.

Comment: Also you didn't show us the declaration of `a`, soooooo `var _a = 0; var a: Int { _a += 1; return _a }` :)

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? It's a legitimate question. You should post your comments as an answer, @Hamish

Comment: @Alexander I suspect people see it as an attempt to recreate the votes the JavaScript version got

Comment: @SterlingArcher So? If it's a valid question, who cares?

Comment: @Hamish You would need to define a new `==` operator that takes `() -> Int` and `Int`, because your closure wouldn't be evaluated, otherwise

Comment: @Alexander Nope, `a` is a computed variable, not a stored closure :) And while I'm not one of the downvoters, IMO this question is too broad and should be closed as such.

Comment: @Hamish What makes it broad? The vast number of answers that exist?

Comment: @Alexander Precisely

Comment: @Hamish Ah, so that's pretty much what I did in my answer, hah

Comment: @Hamish That's sketchy though. A person asking this question clearly wouldn't know that it has many answers, and that it would be closed for that. The question itself (in isolation from the number of anticipated answers) is well defined

Comment: I don't find it too broad, off topic, or really fitting of any of the close reasons. but... i don't see it as being particularly useful, which is also why i downvoted the original.

Comment: @Alexander One only has to look at the original JS question to see the variety of answers that it has received; it's not unreasonable to assume that the same question for another language would be any different. Though that being said, the JS question was temporarily closed as being too broad before being re-opened (and staying that way, even after mods visiting), so it seems the mood of the community is that such questions aren't considered too broad.

Comment: @Alexander Btw, my most horrific attempt at this [now looks like this](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/6c7d7ccf2e6aacb4163fe8d72f74eade) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can overload `==` operator for `Int` type

```
extension Int {
    static func == (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool
    {
        print("== overloading")
        return rhs > 0 && rhs < 4
    }
}

let a = 1;
if a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3 {
    print("PASS"); //always will pass
}else{
    print("FAIL"); //will never execute
}
```

Comment: Even simpler, just `return true`!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example, that doesn't involve sneaky redefinitions of `==` and `&&`:

```
struct Counter {
    var count = 0
    mutating func increment() { count += 1 }

    var a: Int {
        mutating get {
            increment()
            return count
        }
    }

    mutating func sneakyFunction() {
        if a==1 && a==2 && a==3 {
            print("amazing");
        }
    }
}

var c = Counter()
c.sneakyFunction() // => amazing
```