# How to overload equality operator?

Tags: elixir

In swift for example, you can overload the equality operator as follows:

[Overloading equivalence (==) operator for custom class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848119/overloading-equivalence-operator-for-custom-class-in-swift)

```
class CustomClass: Equatable {
    var id = "my id"
}

func ==(left: CustomClass, right: CustomClass) -> Bool {
    return left.id == right.id
}
```

Is there a way to do this in elixir?

What I want to achieve is this:

```
defmodule IP do
  @enforce_keys [:host, :port]
  defstruct [:host, :port, failures: 0, timeouts: 0]

  @type t :: %IP{host: String.t(), port: integer, failures: integer, timeouts: integer}

  # I want the == operator compare host and port but not failures and timeouts..
  def compare(l, r) do
    l.host == r.host && l.port == r.port
  end
end
```

Comment: No. The general way to do this is to create a `compare/2` function within the module that defines your type.

Comment: @JustinWood Thank you. I implemented `compare/2` in my struct but calling `s1 == s2` still return false. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Implementing the function doesn't overload the operator. It just creates a function you can use to compare two structs. So instead of checking `s1 == s2`, you would check `IP.compare(s1, s2)`. But you could name your function whatever you want. A convention for functions returning boolean is to name them with a question mark: `IP.equal?(s1, s2)`

Comment: @BrettBeatty Thank you. I wanted structs to be compared as equals when inserted inside a `MapSet`, but this doesn't seem possible, since they use the `:erlang.===` to compare elements, and it doesn't seem overloadable.

Answer (score 1):

```
defmodule IP do
  defstruct [:host, :port, :name]

  def left_ip == right_ip do
    Kernel.==(left_ip.host, right_ip.host) &&
    Kernel.==(left_ip.port, right_ip.port)
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex ip.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> left_ip = %IP{host: 10, port: 3, name: "Joe"}   
%IP{host: 10, name: "Joe", port: 3}

iex(2)> right_ip = %IP{host: 10, port: 3, name: "Karen"}
%IP{host: 10, name: "Karen", port: 3}

iex(3)> left_ip == right_ip
false

iex(4)> import Kernel, except: [==: 2]
Kernel

iex(5)> left_ip == right_ip           
** (CompileError) iex:5: undefined function ==/2

iex(5)> import IP                     
IP

iex(6)> left_ip == right_ip
true
```

Kernel is automatically imported into iex, so you have to import Kernel again excepting the function `Kernel.==()`.

An `import statement` has to do with namespacing.  By importing `IP`, you no longer have to precede a function's name with the module name:

```
IP.==(left, right)

v.

left == right
```

> I wanted structs to be compared as equals when inserted inside a MapSet

No worky with MapSets:

```
iex(24)> left_ip == right_ip
true

iex(27)> ms = MapSet.new()  
#MapSet<[]>                                                

iex(28)> ms |> MapSet.put("hello") |> MapSet.put(left_ip) |> MapSet.put("hello") |> MapSet.put(right_ip) |> MapSet.put(left_ip) 
#MapSet<[
  %IP{host: 10, name: "Joe", port: 3},
  %IP{host: 10, name: "Karen", port: 3},
  "hello"
]>
```

`Mapset.put` calls `Map.put` which calls `:maps.put`--which is an erlang function.

Comment: `def %IP{host: host, port: port} == %IP{host: host, port: port}, do: true; def _ == _, do: false` looks a bit more Elixirish.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, Nice suggestion.  Not only does it check the argument types, it sidesteps `Kernel.==()` by using pattern matching: `=`.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s not achievable with `MapSet` out of the box, one might easily implement this on their own. `MapSet` is a [no-brainer](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/map_set.ex#L45), it’s a simple map under the hood.

```
defmodule IPs do
  defstruct m: %{}

  def put_new(%IPs{m: m}, %IP{host: host, port: port} = ip)
    %IPs{m | Map.put_new(m, {host, port}, {host, port}, ip)}
  end

  def values(%IPs{m: m}), do: Map.values(m)
end
```

You can also implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) behaviour, or delegate all the functions you need to the underlying map, or replicate the whole `MapSet` behaviour.