# Overriding equals with generic class

Tags: swift, generics

I created a class which is meant to be used as an "abstract class" (only to be subclassed, not instantiated directly). Since Swift doesn't support this, is has to be emulated using e.g. fatalError in body of abstract method.

My abstract class has to be equatable. So I thought, I use fatalError in equals method:

```
class MySuperClass:Equatable {
}

func ==(lhs: MySuperClass, rhs: MySuperClass) -> Bool {
    fatalError("Must override")
}

class MySubClass:MySuperClass {
    let id:Int

    init(_ id:Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

func ==(lhs: MySubClass, rhs: MySubClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}


let a = MySubClass(1)
let b = MySubClass(2)
let c = MySubClass(2)

a == b
b == c
```

And this works. I have the little problem though that my subclass has a type parameter. Now the example looks like this:

```
class MySuperClass:Equatable {
}

func ==(lhs: MySuperClass, rhs: MySuperClass) -> Bool {
    fatalError("Must override")
}

class MySubClass<T>:MySuperClass {
    let id:Int

    init(_ id:Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

func ==<T>(lhs: MySubClass<T>, rhs: MySubClass<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}


let a = MySubClass<Any>(1)
let b = MySubClass<Any>(2)
let c = MySubClass<Any>(2)

a == b
b == c
```

And now it crashes, because it doesn't "see" the overriding equals, and it executes only equals in the superclass.

I know Swift has some issues concerning overrides using generic types. I thought though that this was limited to interaction with obj-c. This looks at least like a language deficiency, or bug, why would equals of generic class B not override equals of class A, if B is a subclass of A?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question originally – this isn’t a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28793218/3925941 as you are asking about overloading and generics rather than dynamic dispatch.  Though much of what is covered in that question applies here too in terms of equality and inheritance hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Airspeed suggests the problem is that operator's implementation is not a part of class/struct implementation => hence, inheritance does not work there.

What you can do is to keep the logic *inside* of the class implementation and make operators use it.  E.g. the following will do what you need:

```
class MySuperClass: Equatable {

    func isEqualTo(anotherSuperClass: MySuperClass) -> Bool {
        fatalError("Must override")
    }

}

func == (lhs: MySuperClass, rhs: MySuperClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqualTo(rhs)
}

class MySubClass<T>:MySuperClass {

    let id: Int

    init(_ id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    override func isEqualTo(anotherSuperClass: MySuperClass) -> Bool {
        if let anotherSubClass = anotherSuperClass as? MySubClass<T> {
            return self.id == anotherSubClass.id
        }

        return super.isEqualTo(anotherSuperClass) // Updated after AirSpeed remark
    }

}

let a = MySubClass<Any>(1)
let b = MySubClass<Any>(2)
let c = MySubClass<Any>(2)

a == b
b == c
```

... as you can see `==` operator is defined only once and it uses `MySuperClass`'s method to figure out whether its two arguments are equal.  And after that `.isEqualTo()` handles the rest, including the use of inheritance mechanism on `MySubClass` level.

**UPD**

The benefit of above approach is that the following will still work:

```
let a2: MySuperClass = a
let b2: MySuperClass = b
let c2: MySuperClass = c

a2 == b2
b2 == c2
```

... i.e. regardless of the variable type at compile-time the behaviour will be determined by the actual instance type.

Comment: Don't have time right now to go through everything, but little observation in advance, about your first comment  - inheritance seems to work, somehow, as you see in the example that doesn't use generics. The problem appears only when using generics.

Comment: Trouble with this approach is now the order of operator arguments alters behaviour:  if you declare `let a = MySuperClass(); let b = MySubClass<Any>(2)` then `a == b` asserts, but `b == a` doesn’t.  Which is not OK as `Equatable` classes must guarantee `==` be symmetric.

Comment: @Ixx: it's not the inheritance that works in that case but type-based binding (see the answer from Airspeed).

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: agree.  For complete symmetry `return super.isEqualTo(anotherSuperClass)` should be used instead of `return false`

Answer (score 1):

In overloading resolution, non-generic functions always have priority over generic ones, so the lesser rule that functions taking subclasses precede ones taking superclasses isn't taken into account.

A possible solution is to make the superclass `==` generic too.  That way the rules for choosing between two generic functions kick in, and in this case the more specific one is the one taking specific classes parameterized by T:

```
func ==<T: MySuperClass>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    // bear in mind, this is a question of compile-time overloading,
    // rather than overriding
    fatalError("Must override")
}

func ==<T>(lhs: MySubClass<T>, rhs: MySubClass<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

let a = MySubClass<Any>(1)
let b = MySubClass<Any>(2)
let c = MySubClass<Any>(2)

// no longer asserts
a == b
b == c
```