# Swift 2.0: Parametrized classes don't call proper == function if it inherits from class that is Equatable

Tags: swift, class, operator-overloading, overloading, language-lawyer

When a parametrized class inherits from another class conforming to `Equatable`, `==` calls the superclass's `==` . Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or how I may be doing something wrong here? I believe an example best illustrates my issue:

```
public class Foo: Equatable {}
public func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool { return false }

//Parametrized
public class Bar<T: Equatable>: Foo {
  public var bar: T?
  public init(barIn: T?) {
    self.bar = barIn
  }
}
public func ==<T>(lhs: Bar<T>, rhs: Bar<T>) -> Bool { return lhs.bar == rhs.bar }

//Non parametrized
public class Baz: Foo {
  public var baz: Int?
  public init(bazIn: Int?) {
    self.baz = bazIn
  }
}
public func ==(lhs: Baz, rhs: Baz) -> Bool { return lhs.baz == rhs.baz }

//Parametrized, no inheritance
public class Qux<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
  public var qux: T?
  public init(quxIn: T?) {
    self.qux = quxIn
  }
}
public func ==<T>(lhs: Qux<T>, rhs: Qux<T>) -> Bool { return lhs.qux == rhs.qux }

Bar<Int>(barIn: 1) == Bar<Int>(barIn: 1) //false
Baz(bazIn: 1) == Baz(bazIn: 1) //true
Qux(quxIn: 1) == Qux(quxIn: 1) //true, of course
```

Comment: Have you used breakpoints or any sort of logging to confirm at all which method is actually being called?

Comment: Yes, I've used breakpoints in my project where this happens. The call skips to the == definition of the superclass, despite the lhs and rhs being the same types. The above example is a toy example I made that is copy-pastable to playground.

Comment: You should probably add the tag `language-lawyer` to this topic as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I didn't find anything on the Swift reference about this, [this gives us a clue](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/10/26/which-function-does-swift-call-part-4-generics/):

> Generics are lower down the pecking order. Remember, Swift likes to be as “specific” as possible, and generics are less specific. Functions with non-generic arguments (even ones that are protocols) are always preferred over generic ones:

This doens't seem to have any relation to `Equatable`, though; this test shows us the same behaviour:

```
class Foo {};
class Bar<T>: Foo {};
class Baz: Bar<Int> {};
class Qux<T>: Baz {};

func test(foo: Foo) {
    print("Foo version!");
};

func test<T>(bar: Bar<T>) {
    print("Bar version!");
};

func test(baz: Baz) {
    print("Baz version!");
};

func test<T>(qux: Qux<T>) {
    print("Qux version!");
};

let foo = Foo();
let bar = Bar<Int>();
let baz = Baz();
let baz2: Bar<Int> = Baz();
let qux = Qux<Float>();

test(foo);  // Foo
test(bar);  // Foo
test(baz);  // Baz
test(baz2); // Foo
test(qux);  // Baz
```

So what is happening here is that **when choosing a free function, along with using its static type instead of the dynamic type, Swift prefers not to use any generics**, even if that generic is a type parameter and indeed it should be the most specialized choice.

So, it seems that to solve the issue, as suggested by @VMAtm, you should add a method like `equalTo` to the class instead, so that the actual method is picked up at runtime.

Comment: This is a good explanation of what is going on, thank you. And you're right, it's more a question about overloaded functions. Would like see Apple have something that goes over this in their docs, it seems like a common gotcha to me.

Comment: I'll leave an issue about this on Swift's repository. Maybe they did mention this but I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say that I'm an expert for the Swift operator overloading, but I found [an article](http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/) you can find some useful information:

> For reference types, the equality becomes conflated with identity. It
>   makes sense that two Name structs with the same values would be equal,
>   but two Person objects can have the same name, but be different
>   people.
>
> For Objective-C-compatible object types, the == operator is already
>   provided from the **`isEqual`**: method:
>   ....
>   For Swift reference types, equality can be evaluated as an identity
>   check on an `ObjectIdentifier` constructed with an instance of that
>   type:

Please, also consider this [answer for similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794214/213550):

> The reason the equality for A is being invoked for an Array that
>   contains B is **that overloading of free functions is resolved
>   statically, not dynamically** – that is, at compile time based on the
>   type, not at runtime based on the pointed-to value.
>
> This is not surprising given == is not declared inside the class and
>   then overridden in the subclass. This might seem very limiting but
>   honestly, defining polymorphic equality using traditional OO
>   techniques is extremely (and deceptively) difficult. See [this link](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) and
>   [this paper](http://www.franktip.org/pubs/ecoop2007.pdf) for more info.
>
> The naïve solution might be to define a dynamically dispatched
>   function in A, then define `==` to just call that:   ... Then when you
>   implement B, you’d **override** `equalTo`:

So, may be the reason that your code isn't work that it's being called after **statical** resolving by compiler, which is being done without knowing that you'll **override** `==` operator for some anchestor of `Foo`.
May be you should do like this (equality logic moved to function being called from operator:

```
public class Foo: Equatable {
  func equalTo(rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    // base logic here
  }
}
public func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
  // check for type here and call appropriate function]
  // may be this will be done automatically as Bar overloads equalTo function
  return lhs.equalTo(rhs)
}

public class Bar<T: Equatable>: Foo {
  public var bar: T?
  public init(barIn: T?) {
    self.bar = barIn
  }
  override func equalTo(rhs: Foo) {
    // cast rhs to Foo here
    // if it can't be done, return false
    return (rhs as? Foo).map { foo in
      return self.bar == foo.bar
    } ?? false
  }
}
```

Comment: Though this might resolve the issue, this doesn't answer the question. According to the Swift reference, the most specialized function should be called, and this is not happening, even with static types. I probably missed something while reading the reference...